# Rails 5: recalculate sum of selected field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display the sum of the selected field for example `12 multiplied by the price`.

Currently I am able to display the sum once, but when an change event happens the total amount doesn't update in the preview.

My current code:

```
<script>

$(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: '<%= preload_wine_path(@wine) %>',
    dateTyp: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      $.each(data, function(arrID, arrValue) {

      });

      $('#reservation_start_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 2,
        maxDate: '5d',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $('#preview').show();
          $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', false);

          var bottles = document.getElementById("bottles").value;
          var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>

          $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
          $('#reservation_total').text(total);    
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

I also tried to add `addEventListener('onChange')` but I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: 1. Check the console for errors 2. Check what the output of `<%= @wine.price %>` is 3. What `change` event? Your code doesn't show one.

Comment: bottles = document.getElementById(“bottles”); bottles.addEventListener(‘onChange’,(e)=>{ bottles= e.target.value; total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>})

Comment: The console doesn't show any errors, the problem is when I select the an amount of bottles for example "1 Bottle" it saves it in the var bottles as the selected value, but when I change the to "3 Bottles" the value in the var bottles doesn't update.

Comment: there's a typo in 'dateType', don't know if it's related but you might try that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".bottles").on("change", function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: '<%= preload_wine_path(@wine) %>',
    dateType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

          var bottles = $(this).val();
          var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>

          $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
          $('#reservation_total').text(total);    
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This would probably work but, when I implement this the calender isn't working anymore.

Comment: What do you mean with the calendar is not working anymore? Can you show me the html code? Also, can you explain to me, why is the sum code inside the onSelect event of the datepicker? If you leave the SUM code there, the value will not be updated unless you don't select another date.

Comment: Everything works now, I need the sum to be in the onSelect element since the sum only show up after a date is selected. Because the user should see a preview with all details (amount of bottles, price per bottle and total price). I defined a default value before the onSelect element (1 bottle) and after that everything worked.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Post your updated code as an answer, so others with a similar issue will have a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code and found this as a working solution.

```
<script>

$(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: '<%= preload_wine_path(@wine) %>',
    dateTyp: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      var bottles = document.getElementById("bottles").value;
      var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>
      $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
      $('#reservation_total').text(total);

      $('#reservation_start_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 2,
        maxDate: '5d',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $('#preview').show();
          $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', false);

          $('#bottles').on('click', function() {
          var bottles = $(this).val();
          var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>

          $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
          $('#reservation_total').text(total.toFixed(2));

          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

</script>
```